# Laravel modal component dont work via back-end render code

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, components, yajra-datatable

I have a laravel modal component which is called via `data-modal-toggle` attribute. The problem is when I create the button from the backend (via Yajra datatables), It wont work but the other button which has a `data-modal-toggle` in the blade works fine. Any idea how can i render the said modal?

Here is the code from my backend

```
        return Datatables::of($apparatus)
            ->addIndexColumn()
            ->addColumn('buttons', function ($row) {
                return '<button type="button" data-modal-toggle="modal-add-app" class="grantors-btn rounded-full font-bold bg-indigo-500 px-4 py-2 text-white">Edit</button>';
            })
            ->rawColumns(['buttons'])
            ->make(true);
```

As you can see my button has `data-modal-toggle` attribute but when i click it the component wont show.

But in my blade I tried to have some button that has also the same attribute and calling the same modal component and it works

```
<button type="button" data-modal-toggle="modal-add-app" class="grantors-btn rounded-full font-bold bg-indigo-500 px-4 py-2 text-white">Add Apparatus</button>
```

If possible. I want to call the modal via js function

Comment: Well the datatables returns data after the pageload.  so the datamodal did not see this.
I use to have this a lot since back when i was still using jQuery. solved this $(document).ready( and them execute all the js needed for datatables)
I also dumped datatables since it gave me a lot of headache when customizing stulf.

So i now use, react, vuejs, livewire. and if i don't have any of that I use Gridjs.

Comment: I see. but i cant use other frameworks for now since the project is almost done. What should i do about this?

Comment: Best practice is to create a table, forget the logic and css. Just create a table and then start as follows: <table><thead><tr><th>column1</th><th>column2</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>some value 1</td><td>some value 2</td></tr></tbody</table>
The reason behind this that due to logic and focus to the wrong things this helps me a lot in table design.

Answer (score 0):

The button could call a function to show the modal. This what I used:

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-link" @click.prevent="showModal()">
         <i class="fas fa-edit text-warning">
    </button>
</td>
```

And the function to show the modal as below:

```
showModal() {
        $('#exampleModal').modal('show'); 
 },
```

Comment: im not using bootstrap sir

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just add $(document).ready() inside it type you javascript code to open the modal